# I want to insert in wordpress in a textarea custom field a list of links, every link on a new line

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to insert a list of links like this into a textarea custom field.

```
/gcE7YfaQUlScq1gLtexLuC63PHY.jpg
/uLcnCwT6y4FF7y6k8b46mJKrx85.jpg
/am5RPNJ2msb91Uza8wIIxWbjTKp.jpg
/yZ6h8trXDPs7Fgbbs3G95w6yVBj.jpg
/eBnok0SLdJI2oLGn9y8hzb5Qo1S.jpg
```

The list comes from a json that has `\r\n` already, but when I insert them in database they show like this this:

```
/gcE7YfaQUlScq1gLtexLuC63PHY.jpg /uLcnCwT6y4FF7y6k8b46mJKrx85.jpg /am5RPNJ2msb91Uza8wIIxWbjTKp.jpg /yZ6h8trXDPs7Fgbbs3G95w6yVBj.jpg /eBnok0SLdJI2oLGn9y8hzb5Qo1S.jpg
```

I would like to have one link per line. I would really apreciate if someone can help me because I'm searching for 3 hours and can't find anything. I've tried to replace the `\r\n` with `PHP_EOL`, `<br>` and nothing works. They are inserted the same.

```
$data = request("jsonsite.tld");

$json_data = trim($data);
$json_data = json_decode($data, true);

$imagenes = $json_data["imagenes"];

$insert_post = wp_insert_post ([
            
            'post_title'    => $post_title,
            'post_content'  => $post_content_translate,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_type'     => 'tvshows',
            
        ]);
        
        $add_post_meta = array (
        
            'imagenes' => $imagenes,

        );

    foreach ($add_post_meta as $key => $value) {
        
        if( isset($value) ) add_post_meta( $insert_post, $key, sanitize_text_field($value), true );
        
    }
```

Comment: you can use WordPress wpautop() function to replaces line breaks with paragraph elements. also, refer this link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/

Comment: Still nothing: $img = wpautop($imagenes);
the result is the same: 
/gcE7YfaQUlScq1gLtexLuC63PHY.jpg /uLcnCwT6y4FF7y6k8b46mJKrx85.jpg /am5RPNJ2msb91Uza8wIIxWbjTKp.jpg /yZ6h8trXDPs7Fgbbs3G95w6yVBj.jpg /eBnok0SLdJI2oLGn9y8hzb5Qo1S.jpg

Comment: can you share code you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - you need to include the relevant code in your question so that we can see what might be causing the problem and be able to help.

Comment: I've edited with the code that i'm using.